# Smooth @keyframes animation goes discrete on Safari

Tags: html, css, macos, safari, css-animations

I built a preloading screen for a website with a loading bar that is animated with CSS @keyframes. Works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but on macOS Safari it gets very discrete. Here is a video demo of how it looks on Safari: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODV5lN2xZSI&feature=youtu.be

As you can see, loading bar background (gray line) and the bar itself (black line) twitch instead of going smoothly from 0% width to 100%. What could be a problem, is this known bug of Safari? Latest macOS and Safari.

```css
@keyframes loading-wrapper-anim {
  0% {
    width:0%;
  }

  100% {
    width:100%;
  }
}


.preloader .loading_wrapper {
  position:absolute;
  width:0%;
  height:1px;
  background:#dbdbdb;
  top:12rem;
  animation: loading-wrapper-anim 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  align-self:flex-start; /*this one is because of the parent element*/
}


.preloader .loading_wrapper .loading_bar {
  height:100%;
  width:0%;
  height:100%;
  background:#000;
  animation: loading-wrapper-anim 3s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader">
<div class="loading_wrapper">
    <div class="loading_bar">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Smooth animation is expected.

Thank you.

Comment: P.S first double line in CSS (@keyframes loading-wrapper-anim {) code was added by accident :) It is not present inside the actual CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I fixed it is instead of trying to manipulate width of an element (which causes redrawing each time the width changes), did the following:

```
@keyframes loading-wrapper-anim {
  0% {
    transform:scaleX(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform:scaleX(1);
  }
}


.preloader .loading_wrapper {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:1px;
  background:#dbdbdb;
  top:12rem;
  animation: loading-wrapper-anim 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  align-self:flex-start; /*this one is because of the parent element*/
  transform:scaleX(0);
  transform-origin:0% 0%;
}


.preloader .loading_wrapper .loading_bar {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#000;
  animation: loading-wrapper-anim 3s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform:scaleX(0);
  transform-origin:0% 0%;
}
```

I used `transform:scaleX()` in conjunction with `transform-origin:0% 0%` (this one sets center of transformation to the top left corner) to emulate width change without actually changing it.

Conclusion: use `transform` where/when possible. They are more efficient in terms of CSS animations and transitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to force the hardware acceleration by adding a `translateZ` on the animation.

```
.preloader .loading_wrapper {
  position:absolute;
  width:0%;
  height:1px;
  background:#dbdbdb;
  top:12rem;
  animation: loading-wrapper-anim 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  align-self:flex-start; 
  /* Add this */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wouvyg1/)

Alternatively, you can look into using the `will-change` method as a last resort for smoother animations. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Your solution helped me put myself on a right track as well :)